# How to convert a list into a nested lists of fixed length

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, nested-lists, contextmanager

lets say i have text file

```
1234
5678
9012
3456
7890
1245
3678
4367
3454
4536
8768
1678
```

i want to extract all these into  list and then convert that list into a list of lists of length say 2 so it should become

```
[[1234,5678],[9012,3456],[7890,1245]..........]
```

so far i am doing this:

```
with open(infile) as f:
    all_stores =[]
    batch=[next(f).rstrip() for x in range(2)]
    all_stores.append(batch)
```

I also tried list comprehensions . but i am doing it wrong

```
# mylist=[[all[stores] for i in range(10)]for el in all_stores]
```

Would appreciate some help.I am using Python and a windows 10. sorry for being a noob.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it in this way, using  zip function :

#### Pairing the elements

pairs = zip(my_list[::2], my_list[1::2])

Comment: i am not trying to concatenate them.need something like this -->[[1234,5678],[9012,3456],[7890,1245]..........]

Comment: I edited my answer

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks

Answer (score 1):

Could you try this?

```
nw_lst = [[lst[x],lst[x+1]] for x in range(0,len(lst),2)]
```

Here, lst is the list of the numbers at first.

---

If there is a possibility of the length of the list is odd:

```
nw_lst = [[lst[x],lst[x+1]] for x in range(0,len(lst)-1,2)]
if len(lst)%2==0:
    nw_lst.append([lst[len(lst)-2],lst[len(lst)-1]])
else:
    nw_lst.append([lst[len(lst)-1]])
```

Comment: this works but only if the length of nested list i want is 2. what if i wanted 10 or 5? i cant do x+1,x+2....x+n

Comment: i edited  my answer

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks

Comment: if you especially want it in groups of 2, so this solution may shorter in this case.